# While editing an existing Django model, my .save() method creates the correct object, but it doesn't seem to persist through the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a project where I want to give users the ability to update some of the fields on an existing Case they have. I have set up the form and it appears to work. However, when I go to save the new, updated date, the .save() method doesn't work as expected. I do the x = case.save() command, and when I print out "x", I see the expected data that I input in the form. However, immediately after the if statement, it does not persist. The database does not update. Thoughts?

relevant methods in views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login')     
def stopThrough(request):      
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = IDForm(request.POST)
        if c.is_valid():
            val = c.cleaned_data['id']
            urlStr = ("/polls/case/edit/" + val)
            return redirect(urlStr)
    cForm = IDForm
    return render(request, 'caseEdit.html', {'start': True, 'cForm' : cForm })
    
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login') 
def caseEdit(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        check = CaseForm(request.POST)
        print(check)
        if check.is_valid():
            wtf = check.save()
            return redirect("/polls/case/edit/0")
    c = Case.objects.get(victimID=id)
    cForm = CaseForm(instance=c)
    return render(request, 'caseEdit.html', {'start': False, 'cForm' : cForm  })
```

Case model

```
class Case(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='creator', null=True)
    victimID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    
    #service list functions 
    client_intake = models.BooleanField()
    client_orientation = models.BooleanField()
    criminal_justice_system_based_advocacy = models.BooleanField()
    crisis_intervention_or_24_hour_hotline = models.BooleanField()
    dental = models.BooleanField()
    education = models.BooleanField()
    emotional_moral_support = models.BooleanField()
    employment_assistance = models.BooleanField()
    family_reunification = models.BooleanField()
    financial_assistance = models.BooleanField()
    housing_shelter_advocacy = models.BooleanField()
    house_rental_assistance = models.BooleanField()
    interpreter_translator = models.BooleanField()
    legal_services_general_consultation = models.BooleanField()
    legal_services_immigration = models.BooleanField()
    legal_services_family_law_services = models.BooleanField()
    legal_services_victims_rights_laws = models.BooleanField()
    legal_services_expunging_or_sealing_criminal_records = models.BooleanField()
    legal_services_employment_wage = models.BooleanField()
    legal_services_public_benefits_law = models.BooleanField()
    medical_case = models.BooleanField()
    mental_health_treatment = models.BooleanField()
    ongoing_case_management = models.BooleanField()
    personal_items = models.BooleanField()
    protection_safety_planning = models.BooleanField()
    repatriation = models.BooleanField()
    social_service_advocacy = models.BooleanField()
    substance_abuse_treatment = models.BooleanField()
    transportation = models.BooleanField()
    other = models.BooleanField()
```

relevant forms.py

```
        
class IDForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.CharField(label='SurvivorID', max_length=100) 

class CaseForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = Case
                fields = ['creator','victimID','client_intake','client_orientation','criminal_justice_system_based_advocacy','crisis_intervention_or_24_hour_hotline',
         'dental', 'education','emotional_moral_support', 'employment_assistance', 'family_reunification', 'financial_assistance',
        'housing_shelter_advocacy', 'house_rental_assistance', 'interpreter_translator', 'legal_services_general_consultation', 'legal_services_immigration',
        'legal_services_family_law_services', 'legal_services_victims_rights_laws', 
        'legal_services_expunging_or_sealing_criminal_records', 'legal_services_employment_wage', 'legal_services_public_benefits_law', 'medical_case', 
        'mental_health_treatment', 'ongoing_case_management', 'personal_items', 'protection_safety_planning', 'repatriation',
        'social_service_advocacy', 'substance_abuse_treatment', 'transportation','other']
```

I have tried using an UpdateView instead of manually updating. It produced the same results. It appeared to work, but did not actually update my database.

views.py

```
class caseedit(UpdateView):
    model = Case
    fields = ['creator','victimID','client_intake','client_orientation','criminal_justice_system_based_advocacy','crisis_intervention_or_24_hour_hotline',
         'dental', 'education','emotional_moral_support', 'employment_assistance', 'family_reunification', 'financial_assistance',
        'housing_shelter_advocacy', 'house_rental_assistance', 'interpreter_translator', 'legal_services_general_consultation', 'legal_services_immigration',
        'legal_services_family_law_services', 'legal_services_victims_rights_laws', 
        'legal_services_expunging_or_sealing_criminal_records', 'legal_services_employment_wage', 'legal_services_public_benefits_law', 'medical_case', 
        'mental_health_treatment', 'ongoing_case_management', 'personal_items', 'protection_safety_planning', 'repatriation',
        'social_service_advocacy', 'substance_abuse_treatment', 'transportation','other']
    success_url = "/polls/case/edit/0"
```

Comment: you know you are redirecting to ' /0'  ? Here ->  `return redirect("/polls/case/edit/0")`

Comment: Yes. /0 redirects to the stopThrough() method and any other /# redirects to the caseEdit() method.

Answer (score 0):

- In your `stopThrough` method I didn't see any save method after validating the form
- In `caseEdit` pass the instance in `check = CaseForm(request.POST)` so it will be `check = CaseForm(request.POST, instance=c)`, otherwise your are creating new objects instead of editing

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I solved it. Unfortunately, it was even stupider than this. I missed an indent on some random called method.

Answer (score 0):

Solved... an obscure method referenced elsewhere had one singular line indented wrong and was returning something incorrect in the pipeline. If anyone else ever has this issue... I recommend looking EVERYWHERE the code goes. Even the stupid things.